# Laravel adding new comment to column of an existing table

Tags: migration, laravel-8

I want to create a new migration to update the comment of a column. For the migration I think the command `$table->tinyInteger('role')->default(2)->after('ID')->comment("new comment")->change();` in `up()` and `$table->tinyInteger('role')->default(2)->after('ID')->comment("old comment")->change();` in down() function respectively. But I am getting an error `Unknown column type "tinyInteger" requested`. I can update the comment in my DB directly but it defeats the purpose of migration if I do this. Also, if I update the local, I also need to update the staging and production.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

only need to do it in up method

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->tinyInteger('role')->default(2)->after('ID')->comment("new comment")->change();
   });
}
```